# Workaround to Chrome for Android's lack of SVG First-Letter Support

Tags: android, css, svg

## Background

Chrome for Android doesn't support the CSS `first-letter` selector for `text` elements. I've created a very simple SVG to demonstrate the problem. On a desktop browser you'll see three sizes of text, created via the `first-of-type` and `first-letter` selectors. On Firefox for Android you'll see the same thing. On Chrome though, there will only be two sizes displayed.

---

## CODE

#### CSS:

```
text {
  font-size:50px;
}
text:first-of-type {
  font-size:70px;
}
text:first-letter {
  font-size:90px;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="520" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text x="0" y="80">MY WORDS</text>
  <text x="0" y="160">MY WORDS</text>
</svg>
```

#### LIVE RESULT:

[image: Caption]

#### SCREENSHOT FROM CHROME (ANDROID):

[image]

---

## Question

My question is this, is there any easy workaround other than just splitting the words into multiple `text` elements and applying the size to each one?

Comment: Does it work with html text? If so why not do that via a `<foreignObject>` tag.

Comment: I just tried out `<foreignObject><div>` to replace `<text>` and it works beautifully! However, it doesn't work in IE on the desktop. There is a `<switch>` element though, which might let me use both? I'm going to investigate further. Appreciate the help.

Comment: foreignObject is not supported by IE unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use foreignObject, something like this so that it only applies to UAs that support it. Unfortunately this would mean that Firefox which supports foreignObject gets the html code but perhaps that's OK.

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="520" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <switch>
      <foreignObject requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" width="520" height="200">
          <div>MY WORDS</div>
          <div>MY WORDS</div>
      </foreignObject>
      <g>
          <text x="0" y="80">MY WORDS</text>
          <text x="0" y="160">MY WORDS</text>
      </g>
  <switch>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've been playing around with using both. I took your code and my CSS, created a new CodePen with both the `div`s and `text`s, http://codepen.io/Kelderic/pen/xuEze, and I while it works in Chrome and FF, IE won't recognize it. It doesn't see the `div`s, and it won't resize the `text`s.